# xml search element by id

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

Can we search a element by id in xml file using dom parser, for example :

```
<root>
  <context id="one">
    <entity>
      <identifier>new one</identifier>
    </entity>
  </context>

  <context id="two">
    <entity>
      <identifier>second one</identifier>
    </entity>
  </context>

</root>
```

I want a node with id = "one", my code

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = docBuilder.parse(new File("filename.xml"));

Element ele = document.getElementById("one");
```

return null,

is there any other way?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612453/how-to-get-an-xml-id-value-using-java

Comment: tried this                                                      `String xpath = "/root/context[@id=one]";
             XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            
             Node node = (Node) xPath.evaluate(xpath, document, XPathConstants.NODE);`                                                      node is still null

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation for [Document.getElementById](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html)

```
Note: Attributes with the name "ID" or "id" are not of type ID unless so defined.
```

The problem is the `Document` doesn't know that an attribute called `id` is an identifier unless you tell it. You need to set a schema on the `DocumentBuilderFactory` before you call `newDocumentBuilder`. That way the `DocumentBuilder` will be aware of the element types.

In the schema you will need something like this in the appropriate place:

```
<xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `javax.xml.xpath` APIs in the JDK/JRE to find the element by XPath.

**Example**

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = docBuilder.parse(new File("filename.xml"));

        XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();
        Element element = (Element) xpath.evaluate("//*[@id='one']", document, XPathConstants.NODE);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could instead use a third party library like [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/introduction/parsing-a-document) that does the job rather quite well.

```
File input = new File("/tmp/input.xml");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "test");
```

And then you could use something like this:

```
doc.select("context#id=one")
```

Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

try and use XML - Xpath expression it is very easy

```
File fXmlFile = new File("filePath");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);


doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());


XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();

            XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();

            String expression;
            Node node;

            // 1. elements with id '1'
            expression = "//context[@id='one']"; 
            node = (Node ) xpath.evaluate(expression, doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
```